# Missing properties error when using Leaflet in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I am trying to use Leaflet and Leaflet Routing Machine. I used following commands to install leaflet and leaflet routing machine,

```
npm i leaflet
npm i --save-dev @types/leaflet

npm i leaflet-routing-machine
npm i --save-dev @types/leaflet-routing-machine
```

Importing leaflet and using it is fine but when I am trying to use leaflet routing machine it it giving me errors.

Following is my code,

```
L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
      L.latLng(latitude, longitude),
      L.latLng(latitude, longitude),
    ],
    show: false,
    lineOptions: {styles: [{color: randomColor, opacity: 1, weight: 5}],},
    createMarker: function () {
      return null;
    },
    }).addTo(this.map);
```

I am using webstorm as IDE I get 2 errors for both `lineOptions` and `createMarker`. I have the same code in plain JavaScript and it is working fine but for Angular it is giving me this errors.

For `lineOptions` it says following and when I added those missing params, the error was gone but I don't want to put those params.

> TS2739: Type '{ styles: { color: string; opacity: number; weight:
> number; }[]; }' is missing the following properties from type
> 'LineOptions': extendToWaypoints, missingRouteTolerance

And for `createMarker` it says following,

> TS2345: Argument of type '{ router: MapBox; waypoints: LatLng[]; show:
> false; createMarker: () => null; }' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'RoutingControlOptions'.   Object literal may only specify known
> properties, and 'createMarker' does not exist in type
> 'RoutingControlOptions'.

Since it is working in JavaScript why it is not working in Angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createMarker` does not exist on [`RoutingControlOptions`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b6a26dfda9e220fbae649e055ceb6260f741fe71/types/leaflet-routing-machine/index.d.ts#L23).
Remove it from the object.

There is, however, a `plan: Plan` member, of which can be passed a `PlanOptions` to the constructor that does contain [`createMarker`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/b6a26dfda9e220fbae649e055ceb6260f741fe71/types/leaflet-routing-machine/index.d.ts#L92).

[`LineOptions`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/leaflet-routing-machine/index.d.ts#L105) must define `extendToWaypoints` and `missingRouteTolerance`.
If you "don't want" them, set them to values that make sense - something like `false` for `extendToWaypoints` and `0` for `missingRouteTolerance`.

The JavaScript implementation likely ignores unknown and has sane defaults for undefined key-values in the options objects that you pass.
However, the TypeScript definitions are more strict.
There is also the chance that it is not definitely correctly typed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But actually there is createMarker and when I am using it, it does not create the default marker. Got answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41301216/8440358)

Comment: @HAthukorala Maybe I'm missing something, but I don't see `createMarker` as a member of `RoutingControlOptions` or the superinterface `ItineraryOptions`. I did, however, add to my answer a method to set the `Plan`, which takes a `PlanOptions` that does have the `createMarker` member.

Comment: Yes the plan option worked. Thank you very much for your reply and detailed explanation. And also thank you for putting your time to answer this question.